# Is there a "MtGox Live" alternative which supports Euro?

Tags: mtgox, charts

MtGox Live is a quite pretty live market depth graph.

For some reason it only shows prices in USD.

Does anyone know an equally good alternative which supports EUR instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[MtGox Live](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=49831.0) now supports 17 currencies. Use this URL with the desired country code:

```
http://mtgoxlive.com/orders?currency=YOUR_DESIRED_CURRENCY_CODE

  BTC  // Bitcoin    
  USD  // USA    
  EUR  // Euro    
  JPY  // Japan    
  CAD  // Canada    
  GBP  // Great Britain    
  CHF  // Switzerland    
  RUB  // Russia    
  AUD  // Australia    
  SEK  // Swedish    
  DKK  // Denmark    
  HKD  // Hong Kong    
  PLN  // Poland    
  CNY  // China    
  SGD  // Singapore    
  THB  // Thailand    
  NZD  // New Zealand
```

Here is the Euro chart: http://mtgoxlive.com/orders?currency=EUR

Comment: There should be a menu for that. When I'm on the EUR MtGox homepage, the MtGox Live link sends me to the USD version

Answer (score 2):

One of the most popular semi-live market watches is: http://bitcoinwatch.com/ if you click on mtgox, there is a panel on the left which will allow you to select EUR

There is also a #bitcoin-market channel on freenode IRC dedicated to real-time market updates.

Comment: I knew that, it's quite detailed but has an embarrassing interface, confused and full of bugs. Maybe there's something better out there.

Comment: I prefer http://bitcoinity.org/markets - but alas EUR is not an option

Answer (score 2):

This should not be just a comment:

http://bitcoinity.org/markets

Comment: True. BTW, since that comment was written, it also supports EUR now.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried several of them, found the following to best suit my likings:

http://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/

- Live streamed data
- Multi-Currency support
- Depth of market table is great

Comment: Would be great if it weren't bugged... every time I accidentally use the mouse wheel on the graph, it gets mad and I have to refresh the page...